# How to test WSO2 Identity Server federated Authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I’ve made a new Identity Provider and setup it’s SAML2 authentication to our Shibboleth IDP.  How do I “login” using this new setup?

The login link still goes to the IS login page, which is desirable because I need to login as admin to fix things, but is there another login link which will redirect to the IDP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I can tell, there's not facility for testing an Identity Provider.  The only way is to actually use it by setting up the full chain.  In my case I setup API Manager as a Service Provider in the Identity Server, and selected the Identity Provider (mentioned in the original question) as Federated Authentication for that Service Provider.  Then I changed the API Store to use SSO (pointed at the IS).  Finally by attempting to open the store I was bounced to the IS, then immediately on to the Identity Provider.

Unfortunately there are a lot of steps in this chain and a lot of things that could be set wrong.  I was hoping to find a method for testing this one part but as best I can tell there isn't such a capability.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to provide federated authentication for your applications.  Your applications can be connected with Identity Server as service providers.  Then you can defined your external IDPs a trusted IDP. Each service provider, you can select multiple IDPs as out-bound authenticators. There is some [blog](http://soasecurity.org/2014/04/30/integrating-salesforce-with-wso2-identity-server-as-saml2-sso-idp/) about that uses saleforce as trusted IDP,  you can go through it as well

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to login to IS using Shibboleth as IDP, you should edit IS_HOME/repository/conf/security/authenticators.xml to enable SAMLSSOAuthenticator and configure it with the required details.